# Browser game where you play as a brain jumping over hurdles

Tags: story-identification, video-games

In first grade (it was definitely in 2010 or 2011), I remember playing some sort of two-dimensional autorunner-platformer game where you play as a brain with legs on an obstacle course. There were definitely hurles you had to jump over.

The background was blue/light purple, while the objects in the foreground were all solid black. I am about 40% sure it had some sort of score counter. All the colors were completely solid.

You played as a brain with legs. Either the brain or brain-like structures that somehow could move appendages of some sort ate circular objects of some sort.

It was very likely running on Adobe Flash. It was not *NeuroVoider* (completely wrong year, not at all similar) or any of the *Run* games (I have played them, definitely not the same.) I don't think it was on PBS Kids. It was in America, definitely on an English-language site.  I don't think it was explicitly educational, but the site was probably supposed to be, as my teacher approved of this game.

It looked a bit like this:

[image: A 2D image of a brain and two hurdles in front of a bluish-purple background]

Comment: Any recollection of the websites you used to play on?

Comment: @jenayah my teacher let me play it on a school computer, no memory of what site

Comment: Could it be that it wasn't a brain and was actually some kind of stick figure? I remember they were pretty popular a long time ago. Also, if it was a browser game, it was 100% a flash game

Comment: I also found this website: https://www.learn4good.com/games/index.htm, which totally look like a website a teacher would trust to let students play. They date it since 2003, so it matches the year you accessed them

Comment: @moacir any idea what that game was callled?

Comment: No, sorry, I just know it was a popular theme at the time. I just asked because you maybe be misremembering.

Comment: Not to point out the obvious, but have you asked your teacher or any of your school chums?

Comment: @Valorum my friends don't remember it and I moved a long ways so I can't ask the teacher :/

Comment: @Named - That's why they invented facebook stalking

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I am reluctant to post this as an answer, I am very confident that you may be misremembering the solid color part and the game is actually [Feed the head](http://vectorpark.com/head/) (The link does not work for me because I have no flash here)

However on this [Wikihow](https://www.wikihow.com/Finish-the-Feed-the-Head-Game) there is a step-by-step guide that kinda matches parts of your description

> The background was blue/light purple... could move appendages of some sort ate circular objects of some sort.

[image]

And also: Hurdle jumping!

[image]

Comment: That is definitely it! Good job finding it!!

Comment: Glad to help! If you like that game style you may also like Windosill that is on steam from the same devs